# SPF and DKIM is set, but record is not found

Tags: email, server, spf, dkim

I have a few domains hosted on the same server. I have added the record for the SPF and DKIM, however, when I d the SPF record check, it said the record is not found. When an email is sent out under that domain, the SPF is neutral, and DKIM is failed (temperror (no key for signature))

For the SPF, I use the same value for each of the domain names:
v=spf1 +a +mx -all +a:xxx.domain.com

Comment: Are you actually signing your messages? Can you show the headers?

Comment: thanks, I have get my server administrator to add the record for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use some online SPF/DKIM record checkers to check your records, to make sure they are published as expected.

Here is an [SPF record checker](https://dmarcly.com/tools/spf-record-checker). This not only checks the existence of the SPF record, but also the syntax, DNS lookup limit, etc.

Here is a [DKIM record checker](https://dmarcly.com/tools/dkim-record-checker).

Note that after you save the settings, it takes up to a couple of hours for it to propagate across the DNS (although usually much faster).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added value with double quotes.